# Looking for GD tutorial in C/C++

Tags: c, image, graphics, gd

I see a lot of GD tutorials for PHP, even though GD was written in C, not PHP. Could you please suggest any good tutorial for GD in C?

Comment: Did you look around at http://www.libgd.org/Documentation or ask on the mailing list gd-devel@lists.php.net?

Comment: Site temporarily unavailable as of 2012-01, use http://wayback.archive.org/web/20110615000000*/http://www.libgd.org/Documentation if you need

Comment: Direct URL http://web.archive.org/web/20100207231223/http://www.libgd.org/Documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit of googling turned up nothing for me either - this is one of those things, for now anyway, that you must study the API reference and make up your own toy test programs.

Comment: Use the source, Luke!  IMO reading libgd sources would be more useful than guessing how it works through toy test programs.  You can also find sources to other programs using libgd, for example http://www.google.com/codesearch?q=gdImageCreate+lang:c+-file:gd

Comment: +1 ephemient. That's what I was thinking of after days of fruitless searching.

Comment: @Viet -- also http://www.boutell.com/gd/manual2.0.33.html